# Android listing large number of data in a listview based on current location

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I am trying to display a large number of records in a list view and ordering them base on the user location the -nearest first- in range of 15km and the data will keep updating while the user move.

the current approach I am doing is that I do send a request to the server with my current location and the distance calculation done on the server side and the data back ready to use ..

but this approach take so many time that my application couldn't handle! and the application become so slaw..

I thought that I can cash all the data on mobile and calculate it on mobile but the data is so huge!

how I can handle that? any idea ?

Comment: Limit web service results to a small number like 8-10. Then, as the user scrolls, call web service and fetch further records in batches of 8-10 records. You need to change your web service accordingly.

Comment: @TalhaMir but the calculation on the server takes too long as well! it will calculate the distance between all the records each time and then return 10 records...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firebase Realtime Database](https://www.firebase.com/), and make a json with all the details like nearest range etc, then make priorities in your database on how it should update using `Query`. Also if you are going to display large amount of data, you should consider moving to `RecyclerView`.

You can find tutorials on Firebase Realtime Database [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)